# "Trying to get property 'type' of non-object" when try to edit admin

Tags: laravel, vue.js, voyager

Laravel Version: 5.7.14 
Voyager Version: 1.1.1 
PHP Version: 7.2

> "Trying to get property 'type' of non-object"**

1.I am trying to edit admin user

2.there is users nav option when click on it same problem occurring In voyager admin panel. I am getting this issues .

> C:\xampp\htdocs\mfscl_website\vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Http\Controllers\Traits\BreadRelationshipParser.php

```
    $forget_keys = [];
    foreach ($dataType->{$bread_type.'Rows'} as $key => $row) {
        if ($row->type == 'relationship') {
            if ($row->details->type == 'belongsTo') {
                $relationshipField = @$row->details->column;
                $keyInCollection = key($dataType->{$bread_type.'Rows'}->where('field', '=', $relationshipField)->toArray());
                array_push($forget_keys, $keyInCollection);
            }
        }
    }
```

> "Trying to get property 'type' of non-object"

---

If I try to edit users bread getting this error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'type' of non-object
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mfscl_website\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\tools\bread\relationship-partial.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mfscl_website\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\tools\bread\relationship-partial.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions Trying to get property 'type' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mfscl_website\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\tools\bread\relationship-partial.blade.php)
>   (0) Trying to get property 'type' of non-object (0)

```
    <div class="relationshipField">
    <div class="relationship_details_content margin_top belongsTo <?php if($relationshipDetails->type == 'belongsTo'): ?><?php echo e('flexed'); ?><?php endif; ?>">
<label><?php echo e(__('voyager::database.relationship.which_column_from')); ?> <span><?php echo e(str_singular(ucfirst($table))); ?></span> <?php echo e(__('voyager::database.relationship.is_used_to_reference')); ?> <span class="label_table_name"></span>?</label>
<select name="relationship_column_belongs_to_<?php echo e($relationship['field']); ?>" class="new_relationship_field select2">
```

Comment: Please check if row is an object. Maybe doing a dynamic dump dd(). Maybe row is a array and you need to get type as $row['type'];

Comment: this has fixed my issue
 if ($row->type == 'relationship') {
                $options = json_decode($row->details);
                  if ( $options->type == 'belongsTo' ) {
                    $relationshipField = @$options->column;
                    $keyInCollection = key($dataType->{$bread_type . 'Rows'}->where('field', '=', $relationshipField)->toArray());
                    array_push($forget_keys, $keyInCollection);
                }
            }

Comment: Excellent, good job

Comment: If you think the resolution you found would be helpful to other users, feel free to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. Otherwise, you can [delete your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the user_belongsto_role_relationship record in the data_rows table. 
you can refer to this issue:
https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3871

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I posted an answer in https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3871, but re-post here for other users.

Wrong Document:
`{"model":"TCG\\Voyager\\Models\\Role","table":"roles","type":"belongsToMany","column":"id","key":"id","label":"name","pivot_table":"user_roles","pivot":"1"}`

My Solution:
`{"model":"TCG\\\\Voyager\\\\Models\\\\Role","table":"roles","type":"belongsToMany","column":"id","key":"id","label":"name","pivot_table":"user_roles","pivot":"1"}`

Hope it help!